# How to make an input form for an immediately used variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'new' page with a form to create new students.  At the top of the page, I'd like to include a form that says "How many students do you have?" and lets the user enter it as `number_of_students` - this variable would then be passed to the form - something like

```
#{number_of_students}.times do 
  <%= form_for([@student_group, @student]) do |f| %>
  ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>`
```

How can i make the form_for number_of_students to be used in the same page?

**EDIT**:

I used georgebrock's advice and did the following:

First I made `howmany.rb` like so:

```
class HowMany
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :number_of_things

  IS_A_NUMBER = %q(1..1000)

  validates :number_of_things, presence:  true,
                               inclusion: {:in => IS_A_NUMBER,
                                           :message = "%{value} is not a valid number of students" }
end
```

I made the changes in case I want to use this model for other situations - it's just a bit more general this way.  In my controller, I did this:

```
def new
  @student = @student_group.students.build
  @how_many = HowMany.new
  @title = "Add a student"
end
```

And in the 'new' view i have the following:

```
<p>
Use the form below to add your students. 
</p>

<p>
First, how many students do you have in <%= "#{@student_group.name}" %>?  
</p>
<p>
  <%= form_for @how_many, url: request.fullpath do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :number_of_things %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

However, I'm getting the following error: `uninitialized constant StudentsController::HowMany`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `ActiveModel::Model` to `form_for`, which lets you build a form for an object that isn't stored in the database.

You'd need a class that looked a bit like this (in Rails 4):

```
class StudentGroupInformation
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :number_of_students
end
```

Of if you're using Rails 3, you will need to include various modules from `ActiveModel` and declare `initialize` and `persisted?` methods:

```
class StudentGroupInformation
  include ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Translation
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  attr_accessor :number_of_students

  def initialize(params={})
    self.number_of_students = params[:number_of_students]
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Instantiate a new one in your controller:

```
@student_group_information = StudentGroupInformation.new
```

Then you could use it with `form_for`, specifying a custom URL to make sure it POSTs back to the current page and doesn't try to find a `student_group_informations` route:

```
<%= form_for @student_group_information, url: request.fullpath do |form| %>
  …
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer!  See my edit - I'm getting `uninitialized constant` errors

Comment: first `lib/howmany.rb` but changed it to `app/models/howmany.rb`

Comment: You need to rename it to `app/models/how_many.rb`, then the Rails autoloader will be able to find it.

Comment: cool, that worked!  now i'm getting `uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Model` though

Comment: could be this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737289/rails-3-activemodel-cannot-include-activemodelmodel-directly

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought `ActiveModel::Model` was in 3.2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32500/discussion-between-georgebrock-and-dax)